# reference assembly in Powershell script

Tags: powershell

In Visual Studio I'm able to simply add a reference to an assembly, for example:  Interop.ADODB.

How do I do this in powershell?  The following is exploding

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Interop.ADODB")

$conn = New-Object ADODB.Connection
```

And here is the error message

```
New-Object : Constructor not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type ADODB.Connection.
At C:\Users\michaelr\Desktop\jet-project\PS\test.ps1:3 char:19
+ $conn = New-Object <<<<  ADODB.Connection
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotFindAppropriateCtor,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

I'm on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Please include the error message that PowerShell gives you back. Also, what version of Windows (including 32/64 bit) and PowerShell are you using?

Comment: What are you trying to connect to? Depending on the data source a better option may be to use native .net provider instead of adodb COM.

Comment: I'm pulling out the 'Jet OLEDB:Engine Type' property from a .mdb file (JET DB), which cannot be done with the native .net providers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this line instead:

```
$conn = New-Object -comobject ADODB.Connection
```

Powershell understand com object natively (well to the extent it's possible for objects that don't always have a lot of metadata) and does all the interop for you. You just need to tell powershell that it's a COM object. You don't need to reference the interop assemblies explicitly.

Having said that, depending on your task you might be better off using a native .net provider instead of ADODB.

Comment: Thanks, that appears to have fixed the issue.  I'm now running into another problem, I'm using the following in the call to open: "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:/Users/bubba/Desktop/jet-project/Access 2000 Database.mdb", but it's coming backw ith an error about the provider not being found.  I have a small C# project doing the exact same thing successfully.

Comment: And to explain why I'm using ADODB, it's because I'm trying to access the properties collection, which isn't exposed from the newer solutions.

Comment: I figured out the issue, the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider is only available in a 32-bit context.  Now that I've fixed that, it's working beautifully :)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [Add-Type](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849914.aspx) cmdlet, which lets you either compile .NET code into an in-memory assembly, or load an assembly from disk.

Check out the `-AssemblyName` parameter if you want to load an assembly from the GAC, or the `-Path` parameter if you know exactly where the DLL you want to load is.

Comment: The line: 'Add-Type -AssemblyName Interop.ADODB.dll'  resulted in a 'could not be found' error.

Comment: If you're loading an assembly from the GAC, you need to use its strong name, not its file name.  For example, you'd use "Add-Type -AssemblyName ADODB" to load that DLL from the GAC.

Here's a page that tries to explain how Add-Type and GAC-based assemblies work:  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/kyle-neier/2012/06/06/powershell-add-type-wheres-that-assembly/

That said, I forgot to consider whether or not ADODB could be accessed through COM, and since it can, Zespri's answer is probably the best one for this particular instance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer's right in front of you:

`Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type ADODB.Connection`

You need to pass the connection string to the constructor like this:

`$c = new-object ADODB.connection "server=foo;user id=bar ..."`

However, I don't understand why you want to use 1998-era ADODB in .NET when you can use `System.Data` instead. Check out this MSDN article on accessing databases with PowerShell:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh855069.aspx

Comment: The obvious guess would be that I'm interfacing with '1998-era' data in such a way that the new tools don't allow me to do.